# SQL change value if shorter than X

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help with SQL. I need to change some lines in the database like

pseudo-code:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE value1->.length <=4 AND CHANGE value to 0value1
```

Most of the lines have a length of 5 chars. I need to add a "0" in front of all values with a length of 4 chars.

Can anyone help out! thanks!!!

Comment: How about starting with `UPDATE` first?

Comment: Please tell me you don't store numbers as strings and want to add a leading zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE tablename
SET value1 = concat(0,value1)
WHERE length(value1)=4
```

Comment: @Dublay what is data type of value1?

Comment: the value1 data type is int

Comment: int data type does not store leading zero in database so you have to change as varchar

Answer (score 1):

Try this
 `update tablename set value= concat(0,value1) where CHAR_LENGTH(value1)<=4`

Comment: @jeans what difference from my answer

Comment: @Sadikhasan i use CHAR_LENGTH and you was faster in writing!

Comment: @Dublay: I think i made a failure. Please try again.

Comment: an `int` can not have a leading 0!! My this will be the problem!

Comment: yes..found out a few minutes ago. so i'll change to varchar

Answer (score 1):

Just another approach/idea for this (untested, since on mobile!):

```
UPDATE tablename
SET value1 = RIGHT(CONCAT('00000', value1), 5)
WHERE LENGTH(value1) < 5
```

This would also fill up entries with only 0/1/2/3 charachters.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8dd6/2)

Comment: @Dublay I added a SQLFiddle to this, maybe it will help you. Otherwise you'll have to add some information in your opening post, like how your table structure looks like, example data, etc.

Comment: @seph data type of value1 is int then how to concat leading zero

Comment: Thanks! It looks like that INT can't have a leading 0 - that's the problem I think.